# How to add group by in outer join sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am joining same table 3 times in sqlalchemy. I want group by `ecs2.id` if `ecs2.school_class_id == None` (Group by in case it did return any result).

I have added group by 'ecs2.id' but it groups but its grouping if ecs2.id is None. Which means its returning None so any result that joins `ecs2` is empty then only one result is returning

This query works fine but some times mutipple records returning where duplicate `ecs.id` or `ecs.school_class_id`

```
ecs1 = aliased(EmployeeClassSubject)
ecs2 = aliased(EmployeeClassSubject)
ecs3 = aliased(EmployeeClassSubject)
sc1 = aliased(SchoolClass)
sc2 = aliased(SchoolClass)
e1 = aliased(Employee)
e2 = aliased(Employee)
emp = db.session.query(e1, School.name, ecs1, ecs2, sc1, sc2, Subject.id, 
                         Subject.name,BusInf,ecs3.employee_id,e2.name).\
    join(School, School.id == e1.school_id).\
    outerjoin(sc1, and_(sc1.school_id == School.id,
                         sc1.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value,
                         e1.employee_type.in_(super_users))).\
    outerjoin(ecs1, and_(ecs1.school_class_id == sc1.id,
                         ecs1.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value,
                         ecs1.relation == OtherType.CLASS_TEACHER.value)).\
    outerjoin(e2, e2.id == ecs1.employee_id).\
    outerjoin(ecs2, and_(ecs2.employee_id == e1.id,
                         ecs2.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value,
                         e1.employee_type.notin_(super_users))).\
    outerjoin(sc2, and_(sc2.id == ecs2.school_class_id,
                         sc2.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value)).\
    outerjoin(ecs3, and_(ecs3.school_class_id == ecs2.school_class_id,
                         ecs3.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value,
                         ecs3.relation == OtherType.CLASS_TEACHER.value)).\
    outerjoin(Subject, and_(Subject.id == ecs2.subject_id,
                         ecs2.subject_id != None)).\
    outerjoin(BusInf, and_(BusInf.contact_person == e1.id,
                         e1.employee_type == UserType.SUPPORTINGSTAFF.value)).\
    filter(e1.id == login_employee[2].id).\
    order_by(sc1.standard, sc1.division, sc2.standard, sc2.division).all()
```

When i added the group by function

```
ecs1 = aliased(EmployeeClassSubject)
ecs2 = aliased(EmployeeClassSubject)
ecs3 = aliased(EmployeeClassSubject)
sc1 = aliased(SchoolClass)
sc2 = aliased(SchoolClass)
e1 = aliased(Employee)
e2 = aliased(Employee)
emp = db.session.query(e1, School.name, ecs1, ecs2, sc1, sc2, Subject.id, 
                         Subject.name,BusInf,ecs3.employee_id,e2.name).\
    join(School, School.id == e1.school_id).\
    outerjoin(sc1, and_(sc1.school_id == School.id,
                         sc1.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value,
                         e1.employee_type.in_(super_users))).\
    outerjoin(ecs1, and_(ecs1.school_class_id == sc1.id,
                         ecs1.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value,
                         ecs1.relation == OtherType.CLASS_TEACHER.value)).\
    outerjoin(e2, e2.id == ecs1.employee_id).\
    outerjoin(ecs2, and_(ecs2.employee_id == e1.id,
                         ecs2.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value,
                         e1.employee_type.notin_(super_users))).\
    outerjoin(sc2, and_(sc2.id == ecs2.school_class_id,
                         sc2.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value)).\
    outerjoin(ecs3, and_(ecs3.school_class_id == ecs2.school_class_id,
                         ecs3.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value,
                         ecs3.relation == OtherType.CLASS_TEACHER.value)).\
    outerjoin(Subject, and_(Subject.id == ecs2.subject_id,
                         ecs2.subject_id != None)).\
    outerjoin(BusInf, and_(BusInf.contact_person == e1.id,
                         e1.employee_type == UserType.SUPPORTINGSTAFF.value)).\
    filter(e1.id == login_employee[2].id).\
    group_by(ecs2.id).\
    order_by(sc1.standard, sc1.division, sc2.standard, sc2.division).all()
```

This works fine when there is ecs2 is not None, But in other cases it returns only one result.

Is there any way that group on condition in sqlalchemy.